# Timber: Theme class not fetching the right directory?

Tags: plugins

I am new to using Timber, but I've wanted a way to use Twig inside Wordpress and ran across Timber, so I'm really excited!

To note, I'm also using the starter theme provided by Timber.

In playing around with things, I was starting out by just trying to set a logo image in base.twig. I added this line of code:

`<img src="{{ theme.link }}/static/images/logo.png" />`

This works as expected, except that the url given on output is:

`<img src="http://domain.test/wp-content/themes/theme-name/theme/static/images/logo.png">`

The issue to me is that `theme.link` goes one directory too deep. According to the documentation at https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-theme/#link it should go to the root theme directory, but it's not in my case.

Is there a way to set this or am I just missing something? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bocaj you're doing everything right. Unfortunately, we made a tweak to the starter theme which caused some unanticipated errors like the one you're seeing.

If you can simply move the contents of the `/theme-name/theme/` folder into `/theme-name/` (including `style.css`, `functions.php` and others) the problem will resolve itself and links/paths will behave as expected.

We tried to clean up the organization in a recent update. While it's cleaner, it caused this problem. I'm in the process of rectifying this so it won't lead to errors/questions in the future. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Thanks Jared! I was driving myself nuts trying to figure out what I was doing wrong :)

Comment: @bocaj no prob! sorry to (contribute to) the craziness. The repo is now updated with the "regular" version: https://github.com/timber/starter-theme — I'll re-deploy to WP.org next week

Comment: :) Now that I know what to expect I actually don't mind it being how it was. The documentation was just leading me astray and I couldn't figure it out. I'm really enjoying working with Twig and Timber. I still have a lot to learn!